# Избавиться от лишнего символа в заголовке

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Имеется код для сохранения результатов измерений:

```
def save_data():
    np.savetxt(f'{datetime.today().strftime("%d_%m_%y")}.txt',
        np.array([
            coors_x,
            coors_y,
            res[0],
            res[1]
        ]),
        fmt='%.18e',
        delimiter='\t\t',
        header="x   y   Bx  By"
    )
```

В заголовке должно быть `x    y   Bx  By`, почему то в хедер добавляется еще символ #
Как от него можно избавиться?

Answer (score 3):

В документации к функции [savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) указано, что есть необязательный параметр `comments : str, optional`, который имеет значение по-умолчанию `"# "`. Значение поля `comments` предваряет строки `header` и `footer`.

Соответственно, в вашем случае необходимо задать значение пустой строки.